# Show All Attributes Of Filter Layered Navigation Before & After Applying Filter : magento2

Tags: magento2, attributes, layered-navigation, filter, multiple-select-layered

I am Creating a functionality to show all attribute of layered navigation in magento2. All options of particular **attribute** must **shown** before & after applying filter in layered navigation.

I have debug this class for the same.

```
Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute
```

[image]

Is there any specific method where filter options are added in filter attribute? where i can add all options to filter attribute..?

Comment: Hello. do you know about how to push option in style attribute?

Comment: Without add options from admin or data base.

Comment: do u have ay solution for that same issue facing while implementing multiselect filter??

Answer (score 0):

We have to override Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute File. So Use this link https://magenticians.com/override-model-magento-2/ To override Model in Magento 2.After Override of this model complete do below changes in Attribute.php file of your.

Have to change in apply() Function of Attribute.php file.

Please check `$this->setItems([])` in apply() function and replace this line by this

```
if($productCollection->getValueSearchRequestName() != "catalog_view_container"){
    $this->setItems([]); // set items to disable show filtering
}
```

And have to DI compile,Flush cache,Deploy Static content and remove files from generated folder then check it.

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

rm -rf generated/*

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: there is no getValueSearchRequestName this function